# How is it possible to set weight 1/3 for a RelativeLayout with a minWidth ?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-gridview

I think the title is enough explicit however let's explain it again.

I have a `RelativeLayout` and a `GridView` that I've set `weights` at 1/3 for the first one and 2/3 for the second, but on some screens the RelativatLayout isn't wide enough, so my question, How can I do to make sure my RelativeLayout has enough place ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should post your xml and possibly a picture of what you have/want. Neither of those `ViewGroups` have a `weight` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your RelativeLayout inside linearLayout that will allow you can use weights then

Comment: Same answer than the one to Eu.Dr. Thanks anyway to take time :)

Answer (score 0):

Only a LinearLayout can be used as a parent to use weights. You should have a Layout Structure having a LinearLayout as the parent, having widh=fillparent and weightsum=3 and orientation=horizontal. Then have Your GridView and RelativeLayout be the children of parent LinearLayout. Set Children's width=0dp and weight =1 and 2 respectively. Doing this should do the needful.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I was trying to say. My RelativeLayout and my GridView are into a LinearLayout I know there's only the linearlayout which supports weight. 
Thanks anyway to take time :)

Answer (score 0):

I've change the proportions, here my new configuration: 3/6 RL and 4/6 GV

If anyone found a better to keep the 1/3-2/3 ratio with a minimum width for the first one, he/she can contact me :)